# How can i project a small part of a monitor onto a smaller monitor

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I found a similar thread, but it didnt offer any solution, so here it goes:

I mix paints professionally. I will find the recipe on a computer, then "send" the recipe to a scale where i will do the mixing. A recipe can contain 3-10 components. The scale has a display that tells me how much more i need of the current component, but it will not display what component to use.

The computer i find the recipes on will display the pigments to use, but it is located behind me(cannot be moved anywhere...) So this leads to me having to turn around all the time to find out what component to use, which puts a strain on my neck when mixing paints all day.

So i would like to copy parts of the monitor in to a smaller monitor above the scale. If i were to duplicate the screen, it would scale down to a point where it would be difficult to read. I only have room for a 7-9 inch monitor.

So to summarize: How to project a small part of a big monitor onto a smaller monitor without it becoming unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to change the resolution on the
large monitor to be the same as that of the small screen.
The large screen would show with everything as "blown up",
but it will look fine on the small screen.

You may use the utility
[QRes](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/QRes.shtml#sgal_0),
but there are others like it.

For ease of use, you may create two `.bat` files, put shortcuts to them
on the desktop, and assign them keyboard keys.

The commands in the files will have the format of :

```
C:\path\QRes.exe /x:1600 /y:900
```

Replace in one file the `x` and `y` values with the resolution of the
small monitor, and in the other that of the big monitor.

This way you may switch back and forth between the two resolutions
using key-combinations.

For more information with screenshots, see the article
[How to Create Desktop Shortcuts That Change the Screen Resolution in Windows 11](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-screen-resolution-shortcut/).

For a solution that uses VLC to project a part of the screen see
[How to Project a Part of Your Screen in Windows Operating System?](https://mywindowshub.com/project-part-screen-windows/).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
This is certainly a sollution that might work. I was hoping for a more "permanent" sollution though. Im worried that my colleagues who are of the older generation might struggle with this. Maby im lookin for something that doesnt exist, or requires programming to execute. I was hoping for some kind of program that would let me select what part of the screen i would like to duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure that [this solution](https://mywindowshub.com/project-part-screen-windows/) would be simpler.